# Why does the Android recent apps list show black or transparent screenshots?

Tags: android

Why do I commonly see blank or transparent screens for apps in my recent apps list? Is this a theming problem or a bug in the recent apps list?

[image: black][image: transparent]

Answer (score 6):

I just checked that out myself and my assumption is, that it happens, when the app performs to many tasks in its UI thread and therefore the Activity is not "fully created". In my case I opened the facebook and the twitter app and quickly switched to the recent app mode. Since the data wasn't loaded entirely, Android wasn't able to display a screenshot. Cyril  Mottier wrote a nice article about app startups and how to handle this very specific problem. You can read it [here](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/).

Answer (score 3):

As a developer, you can override this functionality so that your app doesn't show in recent applications, or if you prefer you can just override the thumbnail being generated with a bitmap of your choosing.

This comes in handy if you're developing a banking application that needs to leak no data, or an x-rated application that your users don't want their kids, or their wife, to accidentally see the thumbnail of.

That being said, I just checked on my Galaxy Nexus (with stock Android 4.2), and the chrome browser does show me a thumbnail of the last page I've been on in `Recent Applications` (even if the thumbnail is coming from when I was browsing in incognito mode).

So I'd say, in your case it's probably a bug: may be a timing issue of when the thumbnails gets generated, or perhaps it could also be a caching storage limit issue, or perhaps some unknown other bug. I'm not sure why you believe it could be a theming issue, but I suppose that couldn't be ruled out either.

Comment: `you can just override the thumbnail` how?

Comment: @azizbekian, That's not how StackOverflow works. Now that you know it's possible, you can just search the documentation or use google. This is something that I would have to do myself since I don't remember the answer on the top of my head. And if you still can't find what you're looking, then you should start your own separate question/thread. This will make it easier for other people who have the same question.

Comment: Sir, I'm not a newcomer to the community and I know how StackOverflow works. For me your answer looks incomplete, because it gives no directions to find out solutions that you mention in your answer. `I don't remember the answer on the top of my head` Maybe a link to approprite documentation source/blog post would be helpful both for you and for other readers.

Comment: @azizbekian, My answer only looks incomplete to you because the original question was incomplete (or in need of a rewrite). We're not supposed to answer closed questions (at least, until they're rewritten by the original asker). In addition to that, the original question was completely different from yours. If you want proof of that, just remove the two initial paragraphs of my answer and you'll see that the rest of my answer should still have worked fine for the original question.